# WMQ Client connection with SSL and mqclient.ini

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm trying to configure an MQ client connection (using amqsgetc for the moment).
I need to use SSL to get access using channel authentication records.

It works perfectly when using a CHLTAB, but I can't find a way to do the same using mqclient.ini file.

I *think* I have looked all over the documentation, but do not see an option to specify the cipher spec I need, neither in the ini file itself, nor in an environment variable.

AMQERR01.log keeps telling me my client did not specify the cipher spec.

Below is the mqclient.ini I use.  (the file works fine when I'm using a non-SSL channel)

```
CHANNELS:
DefRecon=YES
ServerConnectionParms=LAURENT_PC450_SSL/TCP/localhost(1414)

SSL:
SSLKeyRepository=C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\LAURENT_PC450\ssl\clientkey
CertificateLabel=ibmwebspheremqlaurent
SSLCipherSpec=ssl_rsa_with_3des_ede_cbc_sha
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mqclient.ini` can specify the equivalent of the `MQSERVER` environment variable or the `MQCHLLIB/MQCHLTAB` environment variables.

When providing the client connection details via `MQSERVER` environment variable or mqclient.ini equivalent you can not specify encryption details.

To specify encryption details you can use one of the follow:

1. Specify this programmatically using `MQCONNX` in the `MQCD` provided by `ClientConnOffset` and `ClientConnPtr` in `MQCNO`.
2. A pre-connect exit can also override or provide the details above by modifying the `MQCD` if present or providing a `MQCD`.
3. If a `MQCD` is not found then a MQ Channel Table pointed to by the `MQCHLLIB/MQCHLTAB` environment variables or the mqclient.ini equivalent of this.

Comment: Thanks, this does seem to confirm what I thought. If I understand correctly, a pre-connect exit would be somthing I'd have to write to set the cipher spec?

Comment: A pre-connect exit would need to provide all connection details not just the cipher spec.  This is because the cipher spec (`SSLCipherSpec`) is just one field of the `MQCD`, when MQ gets to #3 it will only look for `MQSERVER`, `MQCHLLIB/MQCHLTAB`, or mqclient.ini equivalents if the `MQCD` is `null`.  It would be much easier to call `MQCONNX` and provide those details directly than to write a pre-connect exit to do perform this function.

Comment: OK. In my case, the connection is managed by a library I can't change, so I'll push even harder to get the CCDT address the details.

Comment: If your app can take advantage of the CCDT that is the simplest solution.